# How do you get buffs on the hylian shield?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

I've seen hylian shields have buffs on it, but how do you get it? I defeated the stalhinox like 20 times! All I got was a normal hylian shield. I eventually gave up, but I probably still have the save file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The triggers for weapon/shield buffs are linked to enemy scaling:

> The reason I've brought up the previous thread is **because the same mechanics that determine when certain enemies receive upgrades are also used for gradual weapon upgrades**, so it's a good idea to have a grasp on them before reading this.

[This answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/336884/how-are-monster-variant-appearances-tied-to-the-in-game-progression) can give a crash course on how this works.

The first thing to account for is modifier scaling:

> Getting into the meat of things, weapons typically upgrade as such: No modifier-->blue modifier-->yellow modifier-->stronger variant (if applicable)

There is also class variation to account for:

> Because two-handed weapons and spears play very differently compared to the standard one-handed sword, with the former being slow but powerful and the other being weak but fast, their strength thresholds for upgrades differ.

And thirdly, there is weapon tier scaling:

> The third influence applies to weapons that can change into better weapons. I am not entirely sure how big an influence it is, but it would seem that weapons tend to change earlier or later depending on the strength of the better weapon.
>
> For instance, the Soldier's Shield becomes the Knight's Shield much later than the other Soldier tier weapons change, and the Knight's Shield has a much higher proportional strength than the other Knight tier weapons.

So, gaining an understanding of the "point system" can be useful to gain an understanding of *when* this modifier can be applied to the weapons you use. The Hylian shield specifically is the last weapon to receive modifiers:

> **1400.2 Points:**
>
> - Royal Guard's Spear (Blue)-->Royal Guard's Spear (Yellow)
>
> **1500.2 Points:**
>
> - Hylian Shield-->Hylian Shield (Blue)
>
> **1883.4 Points:**
>
> - Hylian Shield (Blue)-->Hylian Shield (Yellow)

[Enemy Scaling in BOTW](https://www.reddit.com/r/Breath_of_the_Wild/comments/6ghtvz/explaining_enemy_scaling_in_botw_xpost_rzelda/)

[Weapon Scaling in BOTW](https://www.reddit.com/r/Breath_of_the_Wild/comments/7nf1iq/explaining_weapon_scaling_in_botw/)

Comment: I already got a royal guard's spear with blue durability up, I think I'm really close

Comment: Actually, I got a yellow attack up buff, forgot about it.

Comment: how do you know if a weapon has a yellow modifier or blue modifier?

Comment: @noah it's the colour of the text that the modifier has.